# GraphQL request json request body could not be decoded:

Tags: json, go, graphql

I am new to GraphQL so I looked at my Postman request.
This is the raw Postman request.

```
Request Headers
Content-Type: application/json
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.29.2
Accept: */*
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: e3239924-6e8a-48b9-bc03-3216ea6da544
Host: localhost:4000
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 94
Request Body
query: "query {
    getTodo(todoId:3) {
        id
        text
        done
    }
}"
```

I tried the following

```
var url = "http://localhost:4000/query"

func TestGetTodoByID(t *testing.T) {
    jsonData := `query {
    getTodo(todoId:3) {
        id
        text
        done
    }
}`

    fmt.Println(jsonData)

    request, err := http.NewRequest("POST", url, bytes.NewBuffer([]byte(jsonData)))
    request.Header.Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    request.Header.Set("Content-Length", fmt.Sprint(len(jsonData)))

    client := &http.Client{Timeout: time.Second * 10}
    response, err := client.Do(request)
    defer response.Body.Close()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("The HTTP request failed with error %s\n", err)
    }
    data, err := io.ReadAll(response.Body)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Error reading response with error %s\n", err)
    }
    responseBody := string(data)
    if status := response.StatusCode; status != http.StatusOK {
        t.Errorf("handler returned wrong status code: got %v want %v",
            status, http.StatusOK)
    }
    expected := `{
    "data": {
        "getTodo": {
            "id": 3,
            "text": "qwert333 hello",
            "done": true
        }
    }
}`
    if responseBody != expected {
        t.Errorf("handler returned unexpected body: got %v want %v",
            responseBody, expected)
    }
}
```

Then I got the following error:

```
api_test.go:41: handler returned wrong status code: got 400 want 200
api_test.go:54: handler returned unexpected body: got {"errors":[{"message":"json request body could not be decoded: invalid character 'q' looking for beginning of value body:query {\n    getTodo(todoId:3) {\n        id\n        text\n        done\n    }\n}"}],"data":null} want {
```

Then I also tried exactly what I found in the Postman console

```
    jsonData := `"query":"query {
    getTodo(todoId:3) {
        id
        text
        done
    }
}"`
```

This gave me a slightly different error

```
api_test.go:41: handler returned wrong status code: got 400 want 200
api_test.go:54: handler returned unexpected body: got {"errors":[{"message":"json request body could not be decoded: json: cannot unmarshal string into Go value of type graphql.RawParams body:\"query\":\"query {\n    getTodo(todoId:3) {\n        id\n        text\n        done\n    }\n}\""}],"data":null} want {
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Neither of the two versions of `jsonData` contains valid JSON data. JSON is a fairly simple format, consider getting familiar with it: https://www.json.org/json-en.html

Comment: This worked: {"query": "query {getTodo(todoId: 3) {id text done}}"}

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Apollo client: How to simply debug a 400 code error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48863441/apollo-client-how-to-simply-debug-a-400-code-error)

Answer (score 1):

The [standard GraphQL JSON format](https://graphql.org/learn/serving-over-http/#post-request) is actually a JSON object.  In a Go context, the easiest way to create this is with a structure annotated for the [`encoding/json`](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/json) package.  (You may go looking for a dedicated GraphQL client package that has this structure predefined.)

So for example you might create a structure for the minimal form of that structure

```golang
type GraphQLRequest struct{
        Query string `json:"query"`
        Variables map[string]interface{} `json:"variables,omitempty"`
}
```

and then create an instance of that structure and serialize it

```golang
query := `query GetTodo($id: ID!) {
  getTodo(todoId: $id) { id, name, done }
}`
request := GraphQLRequest{
        Query: query,
        Variables: map[string]interface{}{
                "id": 3,
        }
}
jsonData, err := json.Marshal(request)
if (err != nil) {
        panic(err) // or handle it however you would otherwise
}
request, err := http.NewRequest("POST", url, jsonData)
...
```

You may find it similarly useful to `json.Unmarshal()` the response data into a structure that has the standard format, with a `Data` field matching the shape of your query.